# How to get equation from OEIS (for a zigzag repeating sequence)

Tags: polynomials, oeis

While trying to find an answer to my own [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608190/formula-to-calculate-how-hours-correlate-to-fixed-interval-maintenance-schedule), I came upon this [helpful math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211322/equation-for-input) where the person who answered referred to OEIS and provided an equation.  I entered my series into OEIS and [received this page](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%202%203%204%205%204%203%202%201%200%201%202%203%204%205%204%203%202%201%200&sort=&language=english&go=Search).  Apparently, this is a period 10 zigzag repeating sequence.

My question is, how can I get the equation from that page so I can adapt it into my program logic?

Comment: What do you mean?  It's perodic, and $a_n$ is determined by $n\pmod {11}$.  So you just need to reduce your index $\pmod {11}$ and use a (very simple) look up table.  Or something like $\min(k,11-k)$ where $k$ is the remainder on division by $11$.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered by someone in [my Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608190/formula-to-calculate-how-hours-correlate-to-fixed-interval-maintenance-schedule/75608731#75608731).  I didn't understand how to read the OEIS result to find the formula for the sequence, which in this case is:

> a(n) = abs(n - 10*round(n/10))